# DataSources specific for Read-Only Operations - Advantages

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, jboss6.x

Is there any advantage in configuring datasources specific for read-only & for read-write operations ? May it be Oracle/ MySQL.

Does **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** or **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver** consider this parameter (RO / RW) ?

Do we get any performance boost / any other advantages defining datasouces this way ?